# Difference between Python "requests" and Linux "curl"

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I tried through several means, but nowhere do I find a satisfatory answer to this -

> What are the differences between Python "requests" module and Linux "curl" command? Does "requests" use "curl" underlying, or is it totally different way of dealing with HTTP request/response?

For most of the requests, they both behave in the same way (as it should be), but sometimes, I find a difference in response and it is really hard to figure out why is it so.

eg. Using `curl` for `HEAD` request:

```
curl --head https://historia.sherpadesk.com
HTTP/2 302 
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
date: Mon, 28 Feb 2022 20:31:30 GMT
access-control-expose-headers: Request-Context
cache-control: private
location: /login/?ref=portal
set-cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=nghpw4qp5cw2ntwmwfuxw3oi; path=/; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
content-length: 135
request-context: appId=cid-v1:d5f9900e-ecd4-442f-9e92-e11b4cdbc0c9
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-xss-protection: 1
x-content-type-options: nosniff
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000
```

and if I use `-L` to follow redirects,

```
curl --head https://historia.sherpadesk.com -L
HTTP/2 302 
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
date: Mon, 28 Feb 2022 20:31:37 GMT
access-control-expose-headers: Request-Context
cache-control: private
location: /login/?ref=portal
set-cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=trzp0bql4nibswux5z5wfayy; path=/; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
content-length: 135
request-context: appId=cid-v1:d5f9900e-ecd4-442f-9e92-e11b4cdbc0c9
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-xss-protection: 1
x-content-type-options: nosniff
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000

HTTP/2 302 
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
date: Mon, 28 Feb 2022 20:31:38 GMT
access-control-expose-headers: Request-Context
location: https://app.sherpadesk.com/login/?ref=portal
content-length: 161
request-context: appId=cid-v1:d5f9900e-ecd4-442f-9e92-e11b4cdbc0c9
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-xss-protection: 1
x-content-type-options: nosniff
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000

HTTP/2 200 
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
date: Mon, 28 Feb 2022 20:31:39 GMT
access-control-expose-headers: Request-Context
cache-control: no-store, no-cache
expires: -1
pragma: no-cache
set-cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=aqmnxu2s3qkri3sravsrs1cq; path=/; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
content-length: 8935
request-context: appId=cid-v1:d5f9900e-ecd4-442f-9e92-e11b4cdbc0c9
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-xss-protection: 1
x-content-type-options: nosniff
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000
```

and here is the (debug) output when I use Python's requests module `requests.head(url)`:

```
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): historia.sherpadesk.com:443
send: b'HEAD / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: historia.sherpadesk.com\r\nUser-Agent: python-requests/2.26.0\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br\r\nAccept: */*\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden: Access is denied.\r\n'
header: Content-Length: 58
header: Content-Type: text/html
header: Date: Mon, 28 Feb 2022 20:36:18 GMT
header: X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
header: X-XSS-Protection: 1
header: X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
header: Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://historia.sherpadesk.com:443 "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 403 0
INFO:root:URL: https://historia.sherpadesk.com/
INFO:root:<Response [403]>
```

which just results in `403` response code. Response is same whether `allow_redirects` is `True/False`. I have also tried using proxy with python code, as I thought maybe its getting blocked as this URL might be recognising Python's request to be a bot, but that also fails. Also, if that was the case, why does curl succeed?

So, my main question here is: `what are the major differences between curl and requests, which might cause difference in responses in certain cases?` If possible, I would really like thorough explanation which could help me debug and resolve these issues.

Comment: Did you try changing the User-Agent?
My suggestion is to use a translator:  https://curlconverter.com/ or Use PostMan until you can make the call work and then export the call to python code (one of PostMan functionalities).

Comment: For the request here, this translator gives exactly the code in Python which I have used to get output in question. However, I have not tried specifying `User-agent`, but that I don't specify in curl either.

Comment: Both `requests` and `libcurl` are separate libraries for making HTTP requests. `curl` is a command-line program implemented using `libcurl`. Once big difference between the two here is that `curl` is using HTTP 2, while `requests` is using HTTP 1.1.

Comment: You are asking more than one question here. Can you edit the post to ask a single question?

Comment: @chepner I looked into that as well, but do you think HTTP version maybe causing this issue? The major difference in HTTP1.1 vs HTTP2 is in multiplexing requests to have faster response, but would that be responsible for the difference here?

Comment: Try changing the user agent like @Pitto suggested, does that change anything?

Answer (score 4):

The two libraries are different but the problem here is related to user agent.

When I try with curl, specifying the `python-requests` user agent:

```
$ curl  --head -A "python-requests/2.26.0" https://historia.sherpadesk.com/ 
HTTP/2 403 
content-type: text/html
date: Mon, 28 Feb 2022 22:30:02 GMT
content-length: 58
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-xss-protection: 1
x-content-type-options: nosniff
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000
```

With curl default user agent:

```
$ curl --head  https://historia.sherpadesk.com/ 
HTTP/2 302
...
```

Apparently, they have some type of website security that is blocking HTTP clients like python-requests, but not curl for some reason.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification here, I really appreciate it. This would help me in resolving this issue, and +1 for that.

Comment: However, would you be able to tell the major (inherent) difference in the two libraries from a technical/networking standpoint?

Comment: I think the difference is that the service you are querying is just not replying to that User-Agent (maybe a feeble attempt to get rid of some scraping?)

Comment: There are too many differences and similarities between the two to try to list them unless there are specific differences you are interested in. With the right set of options provided to each library, the HTTP request bodies they produce may be nearly indistinguishable from each other. They may use different networking stacks, the installed curl version obviously supports HTTP/2 where python-requests isn't. As long as these HTTP clients produce conformant requests acceptable to an HTTP server, their differences don't (shouldn't) matter.

Comment: The problem described in this question ultimately does not have anything to do with differences in libraries, but some arbitrary choice made by the server to block one user agent and not another. Hope that helps!